# Avoiding double clicking event (button + row) with knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following knockout html code:

```
<table class="vehicles" data-bind="with: chosenCategoryData">
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Vehicles">
        <tr data-bind="click: $root.goToVehicle">
            <td data-bind="text: Brand"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Model"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Registration"></td>
            <td><button data-bind="click: $root.deleteVehicle">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>     
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Clicking on any row, will navigate to the detail page.

Clicking on the Delete button will delete the element on this row.

This delete button is located in the very last column.

**The problem** here is that when I click on the delete button, the knockout event called deleteVehicle is triggered (ok) but also the goToVehicle event is triggered (nok).

How can I avoid the click event on the row when the delete button is clicked?

Thanks.

---

UPDATE

Here is the event called behind deleteVehicle:

```
self.deleteVehicle = function (vehicle)
{
    $.ajax({ url: "/api/vehicle?id=" + vehicle.VehicleId, type: "DELETE" });
    location.hash = vehicle.Category;
}
```

As you can see, first I do an ajax call to delete the element. Next I force a reload of my grid. If I use the **clickBubble** event handler, it does my ajax call in my deleteVehicle function but does not execute `location.hash = vehicle.Category;`. So my grid is not refreshed???

Comment: The documentation shows this exact use case under the click binding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clickBubble` binding on the button. It will prevent event bubbling to tr:

```
<table class="vehicles" data-bind="with: chosenCategoryData">
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Vehicles">
        <tr data-bind="click: $root.goToVehicle">
            <td data-bind="text: Brand"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Model"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Registration"></td>
            <td><button data-bind="click: $root.deleteVehicle, clickBubble: false">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>     
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I try with your suggestion with clickBubble but not really what I need. See my update in my question. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work.I don't have any idea why it not working.May be you can a fiddle so that we can figure what problem is that.

This also work as you expected:

Add id to table row and button

```
eg;)  <tr id ="tableRow" data-bind="click: $root.goToVehicle">
        <td data-bind="text: Brand"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Model"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Registration"></td>
        <td><button id="deleteBtn" data-bind="click: $root.deleteVehicle">Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
```

change your goToVehicle method as below:-

```
self.goToVehicle = function(data,event){
 if ( !$(event.target).is('deleteBtn') ) {  
    alert('clicked');  
    //some code here
 }  
});
```

Comment: The problem is that I use sammy framework for client side navigation. And in my delete event I do 'location.hash = vehicle.Category;'. When clickBubble is false, then this code is not executed. So my solution was to adjust my code to proceed in another way. Thanks anyway.